# Home Button on navigation bar does not work

Tags: android

Have anybody an idea, why I can´t use the Home Button on the top left corner of the navigation bar?:

[image: Screenshot of my AVD]

I searched a lot in the internet, but unfortunatelly I can´t find anything.

It seems that Android doesn´t know this as a button, because the method "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)" isn´t called, when i press ist.

My Icons on the upper right corner work quite fine.

I use Android 4.0.3

Please help

Kind regards
Chris

Comment: maybe post some code, to demonstrate what you are doing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` on your `ActionBar` to enable that button to be clicked.